# Xcode not update ionic build

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, build

When i digit this lines command *ionic capacitor copy ios* and then *ionic capacitor open ios* and do the build, the app builded on my phone is an old version and not the last update,

X code version 12.1
Ionic CLI : 6.9.2
Capacitor CLI: 2.2.0

thanks,

Comment: If the the old version is not just assets, and the new version contains new plugins , use npx cap copy ios, then use npx cap sync ios

Comment: did you find a solution? I keep doing the same thing, exactly in doc, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the project first before copying..

Use

```
ionic capacitor build
```

[Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-build)

Followed by `ionic capacitor copy` or `ionic capacitor sync`. If you have added/removed any plugin, use the latter..